# Solving a transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the a transcendental equation, e.g.

```
NSolve[-(1-x)*Log[1-x] - x*Log[x] == 0.5, x]
```

*Mathematica* is not able to solve, wheres *WolframAlpha* -- is able to do it.

The purpose it to find the probabilities for two events in accordance to a given entropy value.

Comment: Try `FindRoot` instead (look it up in the help pages). And be careful that there is a space or a `*` between `x` and `Log[x]` in your expression.

Comment: In particular, `Chop@FindRoot[-(1 - x) Log[1 - x] - x Log[x] == 0.5, {x, 2}]` gives an answer of `0.80029`.  FindRoot is preferable to NSolve for most transcendental equations.

Comment: `NSolve[-(1 - x)*Log[1 - x] - x*Log[x] == 0.5, x, Reals]` ?

Answer (score 6):

```
Reduce[-(1 - x) Log[1 - x] - x*Log[x] == 1/2, x, Reals]
(*
 x == Root[{-1 - 2 Log[#1] #1 + Log[1 - #1] (-2 + 2 #1) &, 0.199709902553977194585}] || 
 x == Root[{-1 - 2 Log[#1] #1 + Log[1 - #1] (-2 + 2 #1) &, 0.80029009744602280541}]
*)
% // N
(* x == 0.19971 || x == 0.80029 *)

Plot[{1/2, -(1 - x) Log[1 - x] - x*Log[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1.  Why not `Solve[-(1 - x) Log[1 - x] - x*Log[x] == 1/2, x, Reals]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I tend to use `Reduce[ ]` when you may expect branching issues. You're right  in this case, though.